# How to close a segment of a buried PE pipe

Tags: civil-engineering, pipelines

For a project we need to repurpose 2 buried PE pipes, by connecting them and closing off segments. My question is about how this closing off can be done.

Some details:
The lines are roughly parallel, DN 600 and DN 350. The connecting piece will be in DN 350. After the connection the pipework will look like an "H", then we close of one branch in each pipe to get a "U".
The medium is air at low pressure. To do the works, the pipes will be dug up.

An obvious solution would be to cut the old pipes and weld or flange the new pipe with a reduction and 2 arches on. I want to know if there's an alternative way, where I use weld on stubs and just close the branches of the old pipes I don't need. How would I close the branches?

Edit to add: After sleeping over this, we will very likely have the old branches excavated and disposed so the question is moot (for now).

Comment: Have you checked to see if premade end caps are made in the sizes that you are looking for? That seems like the most straight forward method.